# Strange expectation errors with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stubbing

I've tested my controller and have got strange errors like this:

```
    expected: ("376")
          got: (376)
    Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

This is my spec:

```
   it 'should send confirm-email if information is good' do
     sign_in user
     allow(Order).to receive(:find).with(order.id.to_s).and_return(order)
     allow(order).to receive(:finalize) {order}
     allow(order.errors).to receive(:empty?) {true}
     expect(OrderMailer).to receive_message_chain(:send_finish_notification, :deliver)
     patch :save_order, {:id => order.id , :order => {:street_address => 'Baker street', :apt => '123#', :zip_id => zip.id, :frequency_id => frequency.id, :amount_per_hour => '5',
                                                  :extras_ids => '', :phone_number => '3213', :credit_card_number => '4242424242424242', :credit_card_cvv => '777',
                                                  :credit_card_expiration => '12/20', :source_information => ''}}
   end
```

And I've got this error in some logically close specs. But some tests passes, like this one:

```
   it 'should not update user data if order errors is not empty' do
     sign_in user
     allow(Order).to receive(:find).with(order.id.to_s).and_return(order)
     allow(order).to receive(:finalize) {order}
     allow(order.errors).to receive(:empty?) {false}
     expect(User).to_not receive(:update_user_data)
     patch :save_order, {:id => order.id, :order => {:street_address => 'Baker street', :apt => '123#', :zip_id => zip.id, :frequency_id => frequency.id, :amount_per_hour => '5',
                                                  :extras_ids => '', :phone_number => '3213', :credit_card_number => '4242424242424242', :credit_card_cvv => '777',
                                                  :credit_card_expiration => '12/20', :source_information => ''}}
   end
```

to_s or to_i doesn't help. The error line in controller -

```
   @order = Order.find(params[:id]
```

So what could be in that case ? 'Cause it looks like some specs passes, but similar to them don't. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which field is giving you the expected value 376?
It looks to me like it's a mismatch between string / integer

Comment: As I said before it's finding order from params[:id]. I tried to change in controller to to_i/to_s (default is string from params), and I tried to change the same things in my specs, but that stuff didn't help.